# How to determine 95% confidence interval for known population variance?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, z-score

Consider group 1 only and suppose that the population variance is 12. What is the 95% confidence interval for population 1?
Group 1 (Experimental Group)
X bar 1 = 33
Sample size = 10
Population variance = 12.
I know that standard deviation is square root of variance.
So sqrt 12 = 3.464101615
So sqrt 10 = 3.16227766
Standard error = population standard error/sqrt 10.
So what I did:
(X bar 1) +/- (1.96)((sqrt (12)/sqrt (10))
33 +/- (1.96)(1.095445115)
33 +/- (2.147072425)
= 30.85 < u < 35.15
I have to round it to two significant digits.
So lower bound = 31
So upper bound = 35

But I am getting this question wrong somehow. Can somehow help clarify where I am making mistakes. Any help is appreciated it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: https://www.socscistatistics.com/confidenceinterval/default3.aspx

Yours looks fine.

```
M = 33
Z = 1.96
sM = √(3.4642/10) = 1.1

μ = M ± Z(sM)
μ = 33 ± 1.96*1.1
μ = 33 ± 2.15
```

Result:

```
M = 33, 95% CI [30.85, 35.15].
You can be 95% confident that the population mean (μ) falls between 30.85 and 35.15.
```